# React hooks component callback only has initial state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react hooks, however I have a problem that I would think is fairly straight forward. Here is my parent component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DragAndDrop from '../DragAndDrop';
import Attachment from './Attachment';
import API from '../../services/api';
import '../../styles/components/attachments.scss';

const api = API.create();

const Attachments = ({attachments, type, typeId}) => {

  const [attachmentData, setAttachmentData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setAttachmentData(attachments);
  }, [attachments])

  function onUpload(files) {
    if (typeId) {
      api.AddAttachment(type, typeId, files).then(response => {
        let newAttachments = response.data.data;
        let newAttachmentData = attachmentData;
        newAttachmentData = newAttachmentData.concat(newAttachments);
        setAttachmentData(newAttachmentData);
      });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="attachments">
      <h3 className="attachments-title">Attachments</h3>
      <DragAndDrop onUpload={onUpload} />
      {attachmentData.map((attachment, index) => (
        <Attachment key={index} attachment={attachment} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Attachments;
```

`attachments` is passed in from the parent component async, which is why I'm using the `useEffect` function.

This all works fine, and the child Attachment components are rendered when the data is received.

I have a callback `onUpload` which is called from DragAndDrop component:

```
import React, { useCallback } from 'react';
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';
import '../styles/components/dragAndDrop.scss';

const DragAndDrop = ({onUpload}) => {

  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
    onUpload(acceptedFiles);
  }, [])

  const {getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({onDrop});

  return (
    <div>
      <div {...getRootProps({className: 'dropzone'})}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );

};

export default DragAndDrop;
```

My problem is, when the callback `onUpload` in the Attachments component is called, attachmentData is the initial value which is an empty array instead of the being populated with the attachments. In my `onUpload` function, I'm posting the new uploads to my API which then returns them in the same format as the rest of the attachments. I then want to concat these new attachments to the `attachmentData`. I need `attachmentData` to have it's filled in value within the callback. Why is the `attachmentData` the initial state `[]`? How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're accessing `attachmentData` in `onUpload` which becomes stale by the time you use it, so to get the latest `attachmentData` you can pass a callback function to you updater function `setAttachmentData` like this:

```
  function onUpload(files) {
    if (typeId) {
      api.AddAttachment(type, typeId, files).then(response => {
        let newAttachments = response.data.data;
        setAttachmentData(prevAttachmentData => ([...prevAttachmentData, ...newAttachments]));
      });
    }
  }
```

If you want to access the `attachmentsData` inside `onUpload`, you can do so by creating a ref and then updating that ref whenever attachmentsData changes, that way you won't have to pass a function to `setAttachmentsData` also:

```
const [attachmentsData, setAttachmentsData] = React.useState([]);
const attachmentsDataRef = React.useRef(attachmentsData);

// Update ref whenever state changes
useEffect(() => {
  attachmentsDataRef.current = attachmentsData;
}, [attachmentsData]);

// Now in onUpload
 function onUpload(files) {
    // Here you can access attachmentsDataRef.current and you'll get updated state everytime
    if (typeId) {
      api.AddAttachment(type, typeId, files).then(response => {
        let newAttachments = response.data.data;
        setAttachmentData([...attachmentsDataRef.current, ...newAttachments]);
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Any way to still get the current prevAttachmentData within that function?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow, can you please elaborate?

Comment: Is there anyway to access attachmentData inside the onUpload function? We can set it using prevAttachmentData, but can we get the new value of attachmentData?